# How to resolve MySQL error "ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'myuser'@'localhost'?"

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to change the password of one of the users on a MySQL database.

When I do :

```
ALTER USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

I get :

> ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for
> 'myuser'@'localhost'

Here are some more details :

- I'm using the root account to do this.
- Also, I can see the name of myuser when doing this :
  SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
- Also please note that the user I'm trying to change the password for might be in use, as it is a very common user.

Can anyone explain me why I have this error ?

If the user being already logged was a reason why I get the error, what would be the solution ?

Here is my version of MySQL :
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Alexandre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your use 'myuser'@'localhost'

You should check  with

```
select * from mysql.user;
```

Which hosts the user has access to.

If the host  is `%`

```
ALTER USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

Comment: Many thanks nbk, this was the right answer, and saved me a couple of hours !

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had tried to manually change the authentication_string data. After that I am neither able to change password, nor the end user is able to login by the new password I provided. I used `SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1("password")))` algorithm to manually update the password and it turned out that my MySQL version uses a different algorithm.

At this point you need to determine the exact algorithm used by your version of MySQL and then manually update the authentication_string. Else it is now almost impossible to change password using `ALTER` and `IDENTIFIED BY` statement.

Only resolution for my case was to `DROP` the user and again create the user again.